# How to skip the stream forward only outher?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have stream RXJS:

```
this.objectsPropertiesChanges$
    .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        debounceTime(this.debouncetime),
        switchMap((reportObjectProperties: ReportObjectProperties) =>
            combineLatest([this.state.selectedRegistryObjects$]).pipe(
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                map(([selectedObjects]) => {
                    return {
                        selectedObjects,
                        reportObjectProperties,
                    };
                }),
            ),
        ),
    )
    .subscribe(({ selectedObjects, reportObjectProperties }) => this.applyChanges(selectedObjects, reportObjectProperties));
```

I want the flow to pass only when the external observer changes. Now, when the internal is changed, the data is skipped.

I think to remove `combineLatest` and transfer `this.state.selectedRegistryObjects$` to `swithMap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you want:
Everytime your outer Observable `objectsPropertiesChanges` emits a value that is different from the previous it emitted you want your inner Observable `.state.selectedRegistryObjects$` to be subscribed to for exactly one value.

Then the following should do what you want as far as I know:

```
this.objectsPropertiesChanges$
    .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap((props: ReportObjectProperties) => {
            return this.state.selectedRegistryObjects$.pipe(
                first(),
                map(([selectedObjects]) => {
                    return {
                        selectedObjects,
                        reportObjectProperties,
                    };
                }),
            ),
        ),
    )
    .subscribe(({ selectedObjects, reportObjectProperties }) => this.applyChanges(selectedObjects, reportObjectProperties));
```

But your final mapping implies that you acutally want to combine both values, in which case your are propably looking for something like `zip`

```
this.objectsPropertiesChanges$
    .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        debounceTime(this.debouncetime),
        zip(this.state.selectedRegistryObjects$)
    )
    .subscribe(({ selectedObjects, reportObjectProperties }) => this.applyChanges(selectedObjects, reportObjectProperties));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `combineLatest` at all here ? You should just place second observable to `switchMap` as you said in the last sequence. You may also use [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) here.